# How to solve : SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, backend

I want to call a function in usercontroller which is placed in another controller. I have used `async function` but still receiving

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

My code is as follow.

UserController.js

```
exports.adduser = async function (req, pic, type, res) {
    await adduser(req, pic, type)
        .then(data => { result = data; res(result) })
        .catch(err => {
            result.success = false;
            if (err.status != undefined) {
                result.status = err.status
                result.message = err.message
            } else {
                result.status = 500
                result.message = "Server Error " + String(err)
            }
            res(result)
        });
    };
    async function adduser(req, pic, type) {
    await schoolController.checkSchool(req.body)
                .then(resp => {}).catch((err)=>{
                ..................
})
})
```

SchoolController.js

```
exports.checkSchool = async function (formdata) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        finder = { _id: formdata.school_id, is_deleted: false, is_blocked: false }
        School.findOne(finder, function (err, res) {
            if (res != null) {
                reject({ status: false, message: "School" })
            }
            else {           
                resolve({ status: true, cityId: res.cityId })
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: change make `function adduser` to `async function adduser`

Comment: `await schoolControler` is in the non-async function `adduser()` hence node is correct with the error message

Comment: by the way ... it seems `adduser` isn't returning anything ... and you're using `await` AND `.then` - which is hardly ever (probably never) a "good" pattern

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I understand your point. But my adduser is performing insertion in `.then`  and `catch` is used to handle any error occured in insertion

Comment: @JaromandaX @Andreas I have edited my post with `async function adduser` but still receiving the same error.

Comment: really, same error? seems unlikely since now you're not using await outside of an async function - perhaps the error is due to some code you haven't shown - the error messages in nodejs usually pinpoint the line of code with the problem

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you so much for your guidance. I finally solved the issue by using `return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {......})` in `function adduser`.